# Will Curl in PHP throw out an exception?

Tags: php, apache, networking, curl, network-programming

This is my code

```
<?php
$url = "http://i.imgur.com/qV39tsL.gif";
$ch = curl_init();
echo $ch;
$timeout = 20;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

In my enviroment, my access speed to internet is a little slow, so sometimes I can not download some gifs from imgur.

BUT what confused me is that I often get an ERROR as follows:

```
**ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.**
```

I looked up in stackoverflow, Curl in PHP should not make server down.

So will anyone tell me why I can get an ERROR 500: Internal Server Error?

Thank you ~~~

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the script without problems.
It might be something on your server with the curl installation.

Check the server error log too to see better the description of the error.
Maybe you need to reinstall curl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested) there were a few directives missing.

Not including a header, would only show the `.gif` file's binary content and not the image itself.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://i.imgur.com/qV39tsL.gif');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Display the image in the browser
header('Content-type: image/gif');
echo $content;

/* You could also save the file to your server at the same time
using the following outside this comment
// save on server option
$fh = fopen('filename.gif', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
*/

?>
```